# In C, how can I know if a string char has a specific value?

Tags: c, string, variables, char, compare

For example,
Supposing that I've created a string called `string[100]` and assigned some values to it, how can I know if the value of `string[n]` is `m`?

I've thought about creating another char variable and assigning `"m"` to it and then comparing `string[n]` to char with `strcmp`, but it seems kinda like a waste of code creating a variable just for that since on the program I'm trying to code I'll have to compare `string[n]` with a lot of stuff.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my poor knowledge on C, I'm starting to learn it today.

Comment: Maybe `if (string[n] == 'm')`? But making a *constant* for the `'m'` probably isn't a bad idea.

Comment: @Hokster: Fred's right.  there is a *huuuuuge* difference between characters and strings in C.  Strings are "hard", and you can't compare them directly, which is why you have to do things like calling `strcmp`.  But characters are easy, because they're just little integers.  So you can compare the value of individual characters using a straightforward `==` operator, and you don't have to worry about array allocation, or null termination, or calling `strcmp`, or anything.

Comment: @Hokster It is unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @fred-larson Oh, I was just about to say that I've already tried that but was getting an error on the compiler but actually it was because I was using " instead of ' , thanks.

Comment: @Hokster: Yes, single quotes denote a character while double quotes denote a string. Like Steve said, *huuuuuge* difference.

Comment: @Fred Larson - _… making a_ constant _for the `'m'`_? `'m'` already is a _constant_.

Comment: @Armali: I mean a constant symbol as opposed to a literal. It could make a big difference for maintenance and readability, depending on what you're doing.

Comment: I agree - especially readability can be drastically reduced by _a constant symbol_. ;-)

Comment: @Armali: “Constant” is a vague term. `34` is a constant because it is a literal that has the same value in all C implementations. `'m'` is a constant because its value is (probably) fixed during compilation, but its value varies between some C implementations. So it is a constant that is variable. For `static int x = 3;`, `&x` is a constant and can be used in initializers as a constant, and its value is commonly fixed during program loading, but it can vary with every program execution…

Comment: … Inside a function, `const int x = y;` is a constant because its value is fixed (as far as strictly conforming code is concerned), but it can have a different value each time the function executes. We have plenty of different kinds of constants that vary in the degrees of their constantness and variability.

Comment: It seems you are talking of some other language than C.

Comment: @Armali: Those statements are all about C.

Comment: In C, a _constant_ is defined as exactly one of integer-constant, ﬂoating-constant, enumeration-constant, character-constant. `&x` is not a constant; `const int x = y;` is not a constant.

Comment: @Armali: Yes, the C standard has a specification (but not, strictly speaking, a definition) for “constant” in C 2018 6.4.4, where the term refers to certain lexical elements. However, it is a broadly used English word, and people do not always use it in the sense of the C standard even when discussing C. Even the C standard does not use it in the sense given in 6.4.4. For example, 6.6 4 says “Each constant expression shall evaluate to a constant,” which clearly means the expression evaluates to a value, not to a lexical element. In 6.6 9, it labels `&x` an *address constant*.

Answer (score 1):

You're just beginning, and strings in C are not as "user-friendly" as they are in some other programming languages, so there's nothing wrong with asking.

In C a string is just an array of characters, with a trailing null character (`'\0'`) to indicate the end of the string. Each character in that array, though, as mentioned in the comments, is just a character, which is a small integer that can be compared with simple operators like `==`, `!=`, `>`, `<`, etc.

If we want to know if a string begins with an `'m'` for instance, we can write a simple function that checks the first element of the array. Please note that C arrays are indexed starting at `0`.

```
int starts_with(char ch, char *str) {
    return s[0] == ch;
}
```

Once you learn how to use loops and other control flow mechanisms in C, you'll be able to do more complex operations on strings. As an example, determining if a character occurs in a string.

```
int contains_char(char ch, char *str) {
    for (char *c = str; *c; c++) {
        if (*c == ch) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be `if (*c == ch) `

Comment: Right. Thank you!